# How can I create two different security zones on Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I need to create two different secured zones. One zone is for user, another one is for admin. If you are authenticated as user and go to /admin page application must redirect you to /admin/login. It means that one man can be authenticated twice on our web-site - as user and as admin.

```
security.yml:
    firewalls:
        front_end:
            pattern: ^/security       
            provider: users
            form_login:
                check_path: /security/login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
              path: /security/logout
              target: /login

        back_end:
            pattern: ^/admin        
            provider: administrators
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admlogin               
            logout:
                path: /admin/logout
                target: /admlogin
```

routing.yml:

```
    security_homepage:
      pattern:  /security
      defaults: { _controller: SecureBundle:Default:index }
    login:
      pattern: /login
      defaults: {_controller: SecureBundle:Default:login}
    login_check:
      pattern: /security/login_check
    logout:
      pattern: /security/logout
      defaults: { _controller: SecureBundle:Default:logout }


    admin:
      pattern: /admin
      defaults: { _controller : SecureBundle:Default:admin }  
    admin_login:
      pattern: /admlogin
      defaults: {_controller: SecureBundle:Default:admlogin}
    admin_login_check:
      pattern: /admin/login_check
    admin_logout:
      pattern: /admin/logout
```

Now I can authenticate twice, but if I logout from the admin zone, system logouts me as user too. How I can solve this problem? And sorry for my english.

Comment: The first question is 'why would you do this?'  If they are admin, then logging them out 'as admin' implies there is a time when you don't want them to be an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [multiple roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles) and restrict ur firewalls so only users with e.g. ROLE_ADMIN can pass. The official Symfony2 documentation gives great examples imho. on how to create multiple firewall setups